# Why do the training and validation loss curves diverge?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, training, overfitting, loss

I was training a CNN model on TensorFlow. After a while I came back and saw this loss curve:

[image: training loss curve(green) and validation loss curve(gray)]

The green curve is training loss and the gray one is validation loss. I know that before epoch 394 the model in heavily overfitted, but I have no idea what happened after that.

Also, this is accuracy curves if it helps:

[image: accuracy curves]

I'm using categorical cross-entropy and this is the model I am using:
[image: model architecture]

and here is link to PhysioNet's challenge which I am working on: https://physionet.org/content/challenge-2017/1.0.0/

Comment: Maybe you should provide a little bit of context, i.e. which task you are trying to solve with CNNs (i.e. which dataset), which loss function you are using, maybe you should do `plot_model(your_model)` and report the architecture of your model.

Comment: I'm trying to classify ECG signals in PhysioNet 2017 challenge. My output is four classes and I'm using categorical cross-entropy as loss function.

Comment: Please, edit your post to include these details (maybe also a link to the challenge).

Comment: I've edited the question.

Comment: Why are you using a CNN to classify ECG signals? Aren't ECG signals just numerical time series?

Comment: Yes but I'm not using them as input to my model, I'm using some time-frequency features.

Comment: Ok. Please, edit your post to clarify that your data is ECG but you're actually pre-processing it first and feeding actually time-frequency features, if I understood correctly. I don't know if this will really be useful to solve your problem, but it might. Anyway, why did you use convolutional layers?

Comment: Because frequency-time features are images, and as you know convs are useful in image classification. By the way,I didn't mentioned that there's an article I'm trying to implement and this is the network used in article.

Answer (score 0):

Follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37044600/sudden-drop-in-accuracy-while-training-a-deep-neural-net) from StackOverflow, I think your problem related to the second cases where your loss gets Nan value.

Maybe you should try to use the larger datatype (for example float 16 -> float 32)

Comment: As I'm using tensorflow's built-in categorical cross-entropy, I think tf's team knows they should take good care of NaN, values. By the way, can regularization help in this situation or should I put weight constraints?

Comment: We have to dig deeper into TF code to get the final conclusion. For the second question, I think yes, regularization is to solve the overfitting problem, here, before epoch 394, your validation accuracy is stable so I can say your model get overfit problem

Comment: Thanks very much, I'll try this and update the question!

Comment: @SepehrGolestanian So, why did you accept this answer? What was the problem in the end?

Comment: @nbro, you look like the admin of this community, I saw you carefully edit nearly all the post and ask in very details :smile:

Comment: @Toby I am a [moderator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75189/287113). I try to ask for clarification and details to make this site a better and more reliable place.

Comment: @nbro I see, glad this community has someone like you

Comment: @Toby exactly! And I'm glad I found this community that has people like him in it!

Comment: @SepehrGolestanian but back to his question, can my answer solve your problem?

Comment: @Toby You mean the NaN thing or overfitting problem?

Comment: I don't know, which one solves your problem :))

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep the training loss value constant. Beyond that, your teaching technique or network model is not suitable for the job. I recommend that you are using MLP.